# FQL geting the Number of messages between you and someone at a certain time

Tags: facebook, count, numbers, facebook-fql, message

See I want to know the message count between me and my friends but not the total over time but at a time I decide for example between july 2010 and december 2010 but there are no way to specificy a timestamp or until parameter in this query

I already tried

```
SELECT num_messages,timestamp ,senders, thread_id FROM unified_thread WHERE 
 CONTAINS('STRING') and thread_id= 'THREAD_ID'
```

I also tried

```
SELECT num_messages,timestamp ,senders, thread_id FROM unified_thread WHERE  
 single_recipient=USER_ID
```

but in this one the timestamp represents the last time the thread was updated so I cant filter by timestamp because it returns the same or nothing.

I finally got to this

```
SELECT message_id,body,created_time FROM message 
  WHERE thread_id = THREAD_ID (INT EXPECTED - OLD SYSTEM )
```

here I get each message and a timestamp from where the message was sent but is there a way to get FQL to count them for me ?

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no `count` method in FQL. You have to bring the results back to your script and count them there.